# PHP Form login failed: Invalid email or password

Tags: php, sql-server

I already create the PHP login form. this login form uses PDO and connects with SQL server 2016. The problem is, it always said that email or password is invalid although I enter correctly. Just ignore about the password. I know about the encrypt. I will encrypt it after this.

Below is my current code:

```
<?php
session_start();

require_once 'configPDO.php';

if(ISSET($_POST['login'])){
    if($_POST['Email'] != "" || $_POST['Pwd'] != ""){
        $Email = $_POST['Email'];
        $Pwd= $_POST['Pwd'];
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM staff WHERE Email='?' AND Pwd='?'";
        $query = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute(array($Email,$Pwd));

        $row = $query->rowCount();
        $fetch = $query->fetch();
        if($row > 0) {
            $_SESSION['user'] = $fetch['Email'];
            header("location: home.php");
        } else{
            echo "
            <script>alert('Invalid Email or password')</script>
            <script>window.location = 'index.php'</script>
            ";
        }
    }else{
        echo "
            <script>alert('Please complete the required field!')</script>
            <script>window.location = 'index.php'</script>
        ";
    }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css"/>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="https://sourcecodester.com">Sourcecodester</a>
    </div>
</nav>
<div class="col-md-3"></div>
<div class="col-md-6 well">
    <h3 class="text-primary">PHP - PDO Login and Registration</h3>
    <hr style="border-top:1px dotted #ccc;"/>
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <form action="" method="POST">  
            <h4 class="text-success">Login here...</h4>
            <hr style="border-top:1px groovy #000;">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Email</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Email" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="Pwd" />
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-primary form-control" name="login">Login</button>
            </div>
            <a href="registration.php">Registration</a>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Can I know what's wrong with my code?

Comment: could you please edit the answer with html input

Comment: Is the password encrypted in your database? If it is then you are searching with non encrypted password for a encrypted one therefore it wont find the record.

Comment: Indeed, this is a check against plain text password. You should really only store a hash value or something encrypted. If you don't know the password yourself (only a hash), nobody can steal it from your DB

Comment: For now, i didnt encypt yet. Yes, I will encypt it after this. But can you solve my problem

Comment: @NipunTharuksha already edited

Comment: @WanDila i think you found a answer. So please mark the answer and be your upvote can motive others too

Comment: o, all the answer is wrong. I already edit my question and it seems failed to login

Comment: *"Can I know what's wrong with my code?"* The fact that you aren't hashing and salting your passwords **before** it gets to the database is a huge problem with your code.

Answer (score 1):

In your form your password field is named `Role_ID` but it should be `Pwd`.

Change password input to:

```
<input type="password" class="form-control" name="Pwd" />
```

Comment: Also, please change type="text" to type="password" ;)

Comment: @rits I already edited. but still apeear "Username and password incorrect"

Comment: @WanDila try removing single quotations marks from your placeholders inside your `$sql` query. `"SELECT * FROM staff WHERE Email = ? AND Pwd = ?"`

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the password

```
 <div class="form-group">
            <label>Password</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" **name="Role_ID"** />
        </div>
```

Change the code

```
 <div class="form-group">
                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="Pwd" />
            </div>
```

Comment: input type should be password, not text ;)

Comment: yeach thats true

Comment: @NipunTharuksha I already edited. but still, appear "Username and password incorrect"

Comment: do you know how to use `var_dump()`

Comment: can use show the value in the db for a particular password

Comment: are you using any encription methods in signup for the password

Comment: dont know var dump. pass are not encrypted